# How to setup a field mapping for ElasticSearch that allows both exact and full text searching?

Tags: indexing, lucene, elasticsearch

Here is my problem:

I have a field called `product_id` that is in a format similar to:

```
A+B-12321412
```

If I used the standard text analyzer it splits it into tokens like so:

```
/_analyze/?analyzer=standard&pretty=true" -d '                                        
A+B-1232412
'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "a",
    "start_offset" : 1,
    "end_offset" : 2,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "b",
    "start_offset" : 3,
    "end_offset" : 4,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "1232412",
    "start_offset" : 5,
    "end_offset" : 12,
    "type" : "<NUM>",
    "position" : 3
  } ]
}
```

Ideally, I would like to sometimes search for an exact product id and other times use a sub string and or just do a query for part of the product id.

My understanding of mappings and analyzers is that I can only specify one analyzer per field.

Is there a way to store a field as both analyzed and exact match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the fields parameter. In your case:

```
"product_id": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
        "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
    }
}
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html

This allows you to index the same data twice, using two different definitions. In this case it will be indexed via both the default analyzer and not_analyzed which will only pick up exact matches. This is also useful for sorting return results:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-fields.html

However, you will need to spend some time thinking about how you want to search. In particular, given part numbers with a mix of alpha, numeric and punctuation or special characters you may need to get creative to tune your queries and matches.